# Pass xmlnamespaces with default as variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML which I am processing in SQL to pass data to SQL Server tables.

XML is as below

```
<SearchProgramsResponse xmlns="http://api.abc.com/2011-03-01/">
    <page>1</page>
    <items>50</items>
    <total>3129</total>
    <programItems>
        <programItem id="7779">
            <name>Coolblue NL</name>
            <adrank>5.4</adrank>
            <categories>
                <category id="34">Shopping &amp; Mail Order Shops</category>
                <category id="43">Other</category>
        </programItem>
    </programItems>
</SearchProgramsResponse>
```

Now I am using below query to get results

```
;with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://api.abc.com/2011-03-01/')
select
    t1.c.value('@id', 'int') as id,
    t1.c.value('(name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as name,
    t1.c.value('(adrank/text())[1]', 'decimal(29,2)') as adrank
from 
    @xmldata.nodes('SearchProgramsResponse/programItems/programItem') as t1(c)
```

But here `xmlnamespaces default` value is hard coded. How can I make it a variable to pass .

I have tried dynamic SQL but getting error
Here is what I am trying

```
DECLARE @xmldata XML 
SET @xmldata = N'<SearchProgramsResponse xmlns="http://api.abc.com/2011-03-01/">
    <page>1</page>
    <items>50</items>
    <total>3129</total>
    <programItems>
    <programItem id="7779">
    <name>Coolblue NL</name>
    <adrank>5.4</adrank>
    <categories>
    <category id="34">Shopping &amp; Mail Order Shops</category>
    <category id="43">Other</category>
    </programItem>
    </programItems>
    </SearchProgramsResponse>';


DECLARE @d NVARCHAR(200)='http://api.abc.com/2011-03-01/'
DECLARE @ns NVARCHAR(max);

SET @ns = '
;with xmlnamespaces(default ' + @d +' )
select
    t1.c.value(''@id'', ''int'') as id,
    t1.c.value(''(name/text())[1]'', ''nvarchar(200)'') as name,
    t1.c.value(''(adrank/text())[1]'', ''decimal(29,2)'') as adrank
from @xmldata.nodes(''SearchProgramsResponse/programItems/programItem'') as t1(c)';

exec sp_executesql @ns;
```

Now this throws error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@xmldata"

because it's variable and I am executing dynamic SQL.

But If I try replacing it

```
SET @ns = REPLACE(@ns, '@xmldata', @xmldata);

EXEC sp_executesql @ns;
```

This will again throw error because can replace table with whole XML.

Is there any other way to achieve this without dynamic SQL?

If not how can I get result in dynamic SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Your XML is invalid - it's missing a closing `</categories>` tag ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass additional parameter to `sp_executesql` which specify local parameter name and value of that parameter :

```
.....
.....
exec sp_executesql @ns, N'@xmldata XML', @xmldata=@xmldata;
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2638)</kbd>**

Answer (score 2):

If the namespace is not needed in the query you can use a wildcard for the namespace and avoid the dynamic query.

```
select
    t1.c.value('@id', 'int') as id,
    t1.c.value('(*:name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as name,
    t1.c.value('(*:adrank/text())[1]', 'decimal(29,2)') as adrank
from 
    @xmldata.nodes('*:SearchProgramsResponse/*:programItems/*:programItem') as t1(c);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, this works well in simple attribute but getting error where attribute has id and text both eg :                                     select
    t.c.value('@id', 'int') as item_id,
    c.c.value('@id', 'int') as category_id,
    c.c.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(300)') as category_name
from @xmldata.nodes('*:SearchProgramsResponse/*:programItems/*:programItem') as t(c)
    outer apply t.c.nodes('categories/category') as c(c)

Comment: @Spenzo `select t.c.value('@id', 'int') as item_id, 
       c.c.value('@id', 'int') as category_id, 
       c.c.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(300)') as category_name 
from @xmldata.nodes('*:SearchProgramsResponse/*:programItems/*:programItem') as t(c) 
  outer apply t.c.nodes('*:categories/*:category') as c(c)
`

Comment: Thank for better query and your help

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
declare @t nvarchar (max)

set @t='DECLARE @xmldata XML '+'
SET @xmldata = ''<SearchProgramsResponse xmlns="http://api.abc.com/2011-03-01/">
<page>1</page>
<items>50</items>
<total>3129</total>
<programItems>
    <programItem id="7779">
        <name>Coolblue NL</name>
        <adrank>5.4</adrank>
        <categories>
            <category id="34">Shopping &amp; Mail Order Shops</category>
            <category id="43">Other</category>
        </categories>
</programItem>
</programItems>
</SearchProgramsResponse>'''

--


DECLARE @d NVARCHAR(200)='http://api.abc.com/2011-03-01/'
DECLARE @ns NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @ns2 NVARCHAR(max);
SET @ns = '
;with xmlnamespaces(default ''' + @d +''') 
select
     t1.c.value(''(@id)'', ''int'') as id,
   t1.c.value(''(name/text())[1]'', ''nvarchar(200)'') as name,
   t1.c.value(''(adrank/text())[1]'', ''decimal(29,2)'') as adrank
   from @xmldata.nodes(''//SearchProgramsResponse/programItems/programItem'') as t1(c)
';

set @ns2=@t+@ns

print @ns2
exec(@ns2)
```