# How to add or change an Xml namespace in SQL Server / Cannot use 'xmlns' in the name expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces

I have a XML column that is not generated with a namespace, meaning no xmlns attribute. Unfortunately, I cannot fix the actual problem, meaning where the XML is created.

For example:

```
<root>Our Content</root>
```

I *can* modify the XML data before it's returned to a particular client that expects a namespace. What I want is pretty simple:

```
<root xmlns="http://OurNamespace">Our Content</root>
```

I tried something like:

```
.modify('insert attribute xmlns {"ournamespace"}...
```

But that errors with

> Cannot use 'xmlns' in the name expression.

My questions are:

1. Is there a technique around this particular error?
2. Is there an alternative or better way to add/change a namespace on a SQL XML type?

This is in a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure.

Comment: Would you please add an example of the XML how it is now and what you'd like to change (=expected output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe as simple as this?

```
DECLARE @xml XML='<root>Our Content</root>';

SELECT CAST( REPLACE(CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'<root>','<root xmlns="http://OurNamespace">') AS XML)
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it did work.  But, it required another Stored Procedure that could be called from an UPDATE since I was dealing with a result set.  So, I finally punted and corrected it in the client.  Not ideal but it was a simpler implementation.  Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 1):

Best alternative I could come up with, select root subnodes and place it between `<root xmlns="http://OurNameSpace">...</root>`.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(e XML);
INSERT INTO @t(e)VALUES('<root><el1>Our Content</el1></root>');
INSERT INTO @t(e)VALUES('<root><el2>Our Content</el2></root>');
SELECT 
    '<root xmlns="http://OurNameSpace">'+
    CAST(e.query('/root/*') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+
    '</root>'
FROM @t;
```

Closest I got with XQuery is this:

```
SELECT e.query('<root xmlns="http://OurNameSpace">{*:root/*}</root>') 
FROM @t;
```

But that selects the first subelement (eg `<el1>`) with `xmlns=""` (`<el1 xmlns="">`). I didn't find a way to remove that. But maybe that is good enough for you?

Comment: I don't think that the **empty default namespace** works... I tried something similar, also added inner element, also taking `.query('/root/*')`, happy about the "correct" result, packed the whole thing in a `SELECT FOR XML PATH` and used `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to set the default namespace. And I got the `xmlns=""` too... I think this is a bug actually...  No chance around string operations...

Comment: @Shnugo Yeah I find it silly too... I tried all permutations I could think of, nothing worked. I managed to use `modify` to insert the attribute, but only by changing the source, not in a select statement.

Comment: @Shnugo hmf wrong attribute, and modify won't take xmlns. I'm stuffed.

Answer (score 0):

While i am still working on this, i am using

```
insert attribute xmlns {"http://www.ms.com"} into (/root)[1]
```

will throw the error

> Cannot use 'xmlns' in the name expression of computed attribute
>   constructor.

Reason for that is described in this article:
[Adding-xmlns-to-root-element](http://exist.2174344.n4.nabble.com/Adding-xmlns-to-root-element-with-eXist-xquery-update-td2189696.html)

To Summarize it, **xmlns** shouldn't be changed in an existing XML construction because in the case of the below possible implementation from [Microsoft Forum: SQL XML Namespace Issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eac2af29-c5f1-4b59-bc52-e4aaf509cc1d/sql-xml-namespace-issue?forum=sqlxml) suggesting that all **existing child elements will have to changed also**.

```
  <row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:ns1="uri">
     <ns1:ProductID>316</ns1:ProductID>
     <ns1:Name>Blade</ns1:Name>
     <ns1:Color xsi:nil="true" />
  </row>
```

Answer (score 0):

that is my solution (wildcards solution from [Pass xmlnamespaces with default as variable in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715666/pass-xmlnamespaces-with-default-as-variable-in-sql)):

```
declare @xml xml
select @xml = N'<table xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
   <name>name_one</name>
   <width>80</width>
   <length>120</length>
</table>'

select @xml

--it's OK
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.w3schools.com/furniture')
select @xml.value('(table/name)[1]','nvarchar(10)')

--it's OK too 
select @xml.value('(*:table/*:name)[1]','nvarchar(10)')

--it's empty
select @xml.value('(table/name)[1]','nvarchar(10)')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).